# Phpmyadmin corrupted

Tags: php, mysql, ubuntu, phpmyadmin, localhost

I'm trying to recover the root password for phpmyadmin. I followed some tricks found on the net, and now I have a deeper problem.

I can't login to phpmyadmin. I'm getting the following error:

```
\#2002 - Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket     '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2) 
The server is not responding (or the local server's socket is not correctly configured). 
Connection for controluser as defined in your configuration failed.
```

I ran the following command to verify if my MySQL is running,

```
mysqladmin: connect to server at 'localhost'
```

And I'm getting the following message:

```
failed error: 'Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket
'/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)' Check that mysqld is running and
that the socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' exists!
```

I'm not sure what to do next.

Comment: Have you tried restarting your mysql server daemon? `sudo /etc/init.d/mysql start`

Comment: I did now.It didn't resolve the issue.

Comment: But are the server up and running? If not this has nothing to do with phpmyadmin instead your mysql server is not starting as it should.

Comment: I made some changes in config.inc.php file.I removed the 'config' and set changes for cookie.Restarted Mysql and Apache.Now the previous error is gone. Now I'm getting error `#1045 Cannot log in to the MySQL server'.Let's see what Google brings out for this new error.